# Add Class to <body> if a DIV has more then 4 elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, count, addclass

I'm trying to add class to `<body>` when `<div class="scroll">` has more then 4 `<li>text</li>` elements.

**HTML:**

```
 <body>  
   <div class="scroll">
   <div>   <!-- Parent Element -->
     <ul>    <!-- Parent Element 2 -->
     <li>text</li>     <!-- Child 1-->
     <li>text</li>     <!-- Child 2-->
     <li>text</li>     <!-- Child 3-->
     <li>text</li>     <!-- Child 4-->
     <li>text</li>     <!-- Child 5-->
     </ul>
   </div>
   </div>
 <body>
```

Means if `<div class="scroll">` has 5 `<li>text</li>` item then add class to `body` like `<body class"popup">`. Any body know how to do this by **Jquery**. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you tried  `$('.scroll li').length`?

Comment: Are those `LI`s added/deleted dynamically or they are available along with page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setInterval (only needed if your li's are added removed dynamically, you may skip it if it's not the case), and check it's length inside and do respective action as needed.

```
setInterval(function(){
    if(jQuery('div.scroll ul > li').length > 4)
        jQuery('body').addClass('popup');
    else
        jQuery('body').removeClass('popup');
}, 1000);
```

Note: You need to place this script before closing of body tag or after of elements for which length needs to be compared.

Comment: why would you need to do this once a second?

Comment: Is it not more appropriate to use jQuery document ready instead of setInterval?

Comment: I guess .. it may be added dynamically .. after page load

Comment: If added dynamically, what guarantee load time to be less than 1 second? I am interested to know please.

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers script is just needs to be place just before `body` closing tag  .. or it can be after elements which require to compare with..

Comment: @kamal pal document.ready is called after the dom is completely loaded. I think it'd be best to use that.

Comment: @psylogic Yes, I am aware of that (thanks for pointing though), but I don't see any harm in placing this script just before body end tag.

Comment: This would be a way to 'watch' the div for anything that's being added dynamically but I think unnecessary for a static page as it will keep firing for the life of the page.

Comment: @rob_was_taken I had already mentioned this thing in my answer **only needed if your li's are added removed dynamically, you may skip it if it's not the case**

Comment: hm, I was agreeing with you even though the OP didn't ask for any dynamic solution. Be kind.

Comment: @rob_was_taken **Being Kind** this is why I left note (as dynamic thing is my guess), if op mention that thing .. there is no need of note..

Answer (score 1):

I think you're after something like the following.

```
$(function() {
    //Will execute as soon as the DOM is loaded
    addBodyClass();

    //Let's say a click function somewhere deletes a LI
    $("selector").on("click", function() {
        $('.scroll li:last').remove();
        //Now there are 4 LIs which means remove the popup class from body
        //So, call the function again
        addBodyClass();
    });

});

function addBodyClass() {

    $('.scroll li').length > 4 && $("body").addClass("popup") || $("body").removeClass("popup");

    //The above is the shorter version of
    if ($('.scroll li').length > 4) {
        $("body").addClass("popup");
    } else {
        $("body").removeClass("popup");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should Work for you

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function(){

   if ($('.scroll li').length > 4) {
     $("body").addClass("popup");
    } else {
     $("body").removeClass("popup");
   }

 });


</script>
```