# How Prevent to load page if <body> has a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i'm asking this question because there are no any answer i have find.
My question is there are any possibility/way to Prevent page load/Site-Load if `<body>` has a class `<body class="unload">` then page will stop loading. 
I can do this by css *but its become hidden or display none*. So i want to know there any possibility/way to Prevent Page load/stop-loding(*stop browser Loading*) *with out display none or hiding* ?.

**HTML:** [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nzc5suee/)>

```
<body class="unload">  
   <div class="wrapper">  
     <ul>    <!-- Parent Element -->
     <li>text</li>     <!-- Child 1-->
     <li>text</li>     <!-- Child 2-->
     <li>text</li>     <!-- Child 3-->
     <li>text</li>     <!-- Child 4-->
     <li>text</li>     <!-- Child 5-->
     </ul>
   </div>
 <body>
```

I mean **browser will stop Loading** immediately if `<body>` has a class `<body class="unload">`.
 Any body know how to do this by Jquery. Thanks in advance.

Comment: only the server can decide on which parts of the page to send to the client - the client gets what the server sends

Comment: @JaromandaX  I mean browser will stop Loading immediately, Then element will not load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

having read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/stop - this may do what you want

```
<body class="unload">  
    <script>
    if (document.body.classList.contains('unload')) {
        if(window.stop) { // all abut internet explorer
            window.stop();
        }
        else if (document.execCommand) { // internet explorer
            document.execCommand('Stop');
        }
    }
    // based on comments
    setInterval(function() {
        if (jQuery('.sly-scroll ul > li, .label-widget-menu ul > li').length > 4) {
            jQuery('body').addClass('popup');
        }
        if (document.querySelector('html').classList.contains('unload')) {
            jQuery('.wrapper').html('');
        }
    }, 1000);
    </script>
   <div class="wrapper">  
     <ul>    <!-- Parent Element -->
     <li>text</li>     <!-- Child 1-->
     <li>text</li>     <!-- Child 2-->
     <li>text</li>     <!-- Child 3-->
     <li>text</li>     <!-- Child 4-->
     <li>text</li>     <!-- Child 5-->
     </ul>
   </div>
 <body>
```

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nzc5suee/1/)
better [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nzc5suee/4/) for Internet Explorer

Thanks to @A.Wolff for the Internet Explorer workaround

Comment: Interresting, the only downside seems to be: `The stop() method is not supported by Internet Explorer.`

Comment: I do look for cross browser compatibility table on MDN pages - this page did not have one, so I incorrectly assumed it's a cross browser standard since javascript was born!!!

Comment: That doesn't really matter because there is a simple fix for IE: http://jsfiddle.net/nzc5suee/2/

Comment: well played, @A.Wolff -  you should put up a complete answer

Comment: I didn't think about it before reading your answer, so you could just edit it to include workaround :)  `window.stop ? window.stop() : document.execCommand('Stop');`

Comment: I've put a different spin on it (rather than try/catch block which I try to avoid if possible)

Comment: Ya, usually better to avoid it

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks, but how to do this for `<HTML class="unload">` instead of `<body>` ?

Comment: try `document.querySelector('html')` instead of `document.body` - can't check in a fiddle, an you're on your own with Internet Exploder if it doesn't play the same as Firefox/Chrome

Comment: Which isn't? body or html? I've checked both and both work in firefox/chrome - post another `fiddle` with your attempt

Comment: @JaromandaX  HTML, I have trying this `setInterval(function(){
 if(jQuery('.sly-scroll ul > li, .label-widget-menu ul > li').length > 4) {
  jQuery('body').addClass('popup');
  }  if else (document.querySelector('html').classList.contains('unload')) {
        window.stop();
    }

else {
    jQuery('body').removeClass('popup');
  }
}, 1000);`

Comment: sorry, why are you putting this in a `setInterval`??? can you see a setInterval anywhere in the code you accepted? - your code has `if else` instead of `else if` in it - still, this wont work as you expect

Comment: window.stop wont stop document loading after document ready - you are adding random code to a working answer as you asked it without knowing the consequences of your random additions

Comment: I know you asked `Any body know how to do this by Jquery.` and are desperate to use jQuery in the solution, but there is no need for jQuery for what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks, Understand, actually on my page `unload` class add to html after 1+ second(or any time), so how exude your js when  `unload` class will add ?

Comment: that requires quite different code in your setInterval - instead of window.stop etc you'd remove the part of HTML you want to remove

Comment: Thanks, i'm going to ask new question, then i will give you question link.

Comment: Thanks this is the code the i'm trying to combine:   `setInterval(function(){
 if(jQuery('.sly-scroll ul > li, .label-widget-menu ul > li').length > 4) {
  jQuery('html').addClass('unload');
  } else {
    jQuery('html').removeClass('unload');
  }
}, 1000);`  And you may find detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31635213/4290783