# How to prevent to load an element of a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31636826/4290783) (50% same) 
I'm trying to unload an element of a DIV by jquery, I can do this by css but its become hidden or display none. So i want to know there any possibility/way to Prevent load specific element of a div. I want to unload second `post-main-warp` of `.widget-content` (*means unload second .post-main-warp*) with out `.hide()`, Is there any possibility/way to Prevent load with out `.hide()`.

**HTML:** [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2k1sczzs/)

```
<div class="widget-content">
<ul>
<li class="post-main-warp">Please load</li>
<li class="post-main-warp">Please Unload</li><!--Unload This-->
</ul>
</div>
```

How to do this by **Jquery/JS**? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use removeChild, to remove DOM Elements, if that's what you want.

Element is the element from which you want to remove child element's from. And index would be the index of the element to remove.

fiddle goes [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tnm08q8x/)

```
function removeSpecificNode(el, index) {
    var children = el.children;
    if(children.length > 0) {
        el.removeChild(children[index]);
    }
}
```

And just for fun, remove nodes till offset.

```
function removeNodesToOffset(el, offset) {
    var children = el.children;
    for(var i=children.length-1;i>=0+offset;i--)
        el.removeChild(children[i]);
}
```

Comment: Just to add a note for OP - this is the easiest way to do this. It does not prevent the loading of anything, but rather removes it if it's not needed. If you were set on preventing the creation of the element all together, you would need to dynamically populate the list

Comment: @fubbe  Thanks, But not understand, how to do this, Please fiddle this.

Comment: @fubbe wow Thanks, but i want to unload second `.post-main-warp` of specific of a div, please

Comment: So just change index to 1 then. It's actually counting within your ul element. First li = 0, second li = 1, third li = 2, fourth = ...

Comment: @fubbe sorry dear don't understand English, Please fiddle this for unload second `.post-main-warp` of `widget-content`.

Comment: fiddle here, https://jsfiddle.net/tnm08q8x/1/
If this is the answer to your question, please accept it ^

Comment: @fubbe Thanks, but ihave to use `.widget-content ul` isnted of ul, because only `ul ` will take effect to all blocks/element of a page, so how to do this specific div like only unload second `post-main-warp` of  `.widget-content` ? please see this: https://jsfiddle.net/tnm08q8x/2/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84825/discussion-between-fubbe-and-aabira).